# How to set fields/model to readonly if one attribute is set to true in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, I got three classes:

```
class User(...):
    #... other fields
    name = models.CharField()

class Equipment(...):
    #... other fields 
    inUse = models.Boolean(default=False)

class Ticket(...):
    #... Other fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(...)
    ended = models.Boolean(default=False)
```

Now, when I create a new `Ticket`, the equipment "inUse" attribute changes to True, so I cannot give the same `Equipment` to more than one `User`. The thing is that when I set the `Ticket` to "ended" I'll still be able to change it to not "ended". I want not to be able to change that once I set the "ended" attribute of the `Ticket` to True.

PS: I'm overriding the method save to make changes in the `Equipment` when setting up a new `Ticket` or changing it to "ended".

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Equipamento, TipoEquipamento, Funcionario, Setor, Ticket

# Register your models here.
class EquipamentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['codigo', 'categoria', 'descricao', 'ativo', 'emUso']
    search_fields = ['codigo', 'descricao']

class FuncionarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['nome', 'setor', 'email']
    search_fields = ['codigo', 'nome']
    

class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'get_user_name', 'get_equipment_name', 'dataDevolucao', 'finalizado']
    autocomplete_fields = ['usuario', 'equipamento']
    
    def get_user_name(self, obj):
        return obj.usuario.nome
    
    def get_equipment_name(self, obj):
        return obj.equipamento.descricao

    get_user_name.short_description = 'Funcionario'
    get_equipment_name.short_description = 'Equipamento'
```

Comment: Is this related to Django admin? If yes then share admin.py code too

Comment: So you want an equipment to be available to only one user at a time and make the `Ticket` read-only once it has ended?

Comment: Exactly @isAif...

Comment: I'm not sure @AkashJoshi... But I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

dumb question, after a few minutes I realized I could set a field like "can
Change" in the model so that when I change `Status` the field will be set to false, and I will not be able to change that model anymore. Daaah, thanks anyways.